# Modify all files in specified directory (including subfolders) and saving them in new directory while presevering folder structure (Python)

Tags: python

*(I'm new to python so please excuse the probably trivial question. I tried my best looking for similar issues but suprisingly couldn't find someone with the same question.)*

I'm trying to build a simple static site generator in Python. The script should take all .txt files in a specific directory (including subfolders), paste the content of each into a template .html file and then save all the newly generated .html files into a new directory while recreating the folder structure of the original directory.

So for I got the code which does the conversion itself for a single file but I'm unsure how to do it for multiple files in a directory.

```
with open('template/page.html', 'r') as template:
    templatedata = template.read()

with open('content/content.txt', 'r') as content:
    contentdata = content.read()

pagedata = templatedata.replace('!PlaceholderContent!', contentdata)

with open('www/content.html', 'w') as output:
        output.write(pagedata)
```

Comment: Is your problem not knowing how to manipulate multiple files inside specific directories, or is it not understanding how to integrate the repetitiveness of the modifications into your code ?

Comment: @Pixel_teK More of the former, I think. What I don't understand is how to recreate the directory structure at a new location and then save the files in the same subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate files and directories, you will need to import some system functionalites under the built-in module `os`.

```py
import os
```

The functionalities under the `os` module include :

- Listing the content of a directory :

  ```py
  path_to_template_dir = 'template/'
  template_files = os.listdir(path_to_template_dir)
  print(template_files)   
  # Outputs : ['page.html']
  ```
- Creating a directory (If it does not already exist) :

  ```py
  path_to_output_dir = 'www/'
  try : 
      os.mkdir(path_to_output_dir)
  except FileExistsError as e:
      print('Directory exists:', path_to_output_dir)
  ```

And since you know the names of the directories you want to use, and using these two functions, you now know the names of the files you want to use and generate, you can now concatenate the name of each file to the names of its directories to create the string `str` of the final file path, which you can then `open()` for reading and/or writing.

It's hard to give a perfect code example for your question since the logic of how you want to manipulate each of the template and content file is missing, but here is an example for writing a file inside the newly created directory :

```py
path_to_output_file = path_to_output_dir + 'content.html'

with open(path_to_output_file, 'w') as output:
    output.write('Content')
```

And an example for reading all the template files inside the `template/` directory and then printing them to the screen.

```py
for template_file in template_files:
    path_to_template_file = path_to_template_dir + template_file
    with open(path_to_template_file, 'r') as template:
        print(template.read())
```

In the end, manipulating files is all about creating the path string you want to read from or write to, and then accessing it.

Anymore functionalities you might need (for example : checking if a path is a file `os.path.isfile()` or if it's for a directory `os.path.isdir()` can be found under the `os` module.